# how to receive the sms for a particular number using sms gateway

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I want to create a service, which enables users to give me feed back regarding my product (for example..this can be anything). Now once the user sends an SMS i should receive it in my PC (No mobile is not connected to PC, when i said some number its some toll free number sort of types) for further processing.

I know the question is bit vague, but basically i need to know how these people who says send sms to this number if you like this particualr product or so do. what technology do they use to receive the SMS from user. If they use SMS GATEways can some one please suggest which gateway is best to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*

Your best solution is probably to use an SMS API. Here are a few providers:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

If you're planning on international support, it's worth noting that as far I a know, Nexmo supports the most incoming virtual numbers (countries where you can purchase a number that allows you to receive messages).

Also, since you'll be receiving messages, Nexmo's pricing model will be better for you. Twilio/Tropo both charge for the virtual number and per message to receive SMS, Nexmo only charges for the virtual number.

All three APIs are straight forward REST/HTTP APIs - so you'll just need a server somewhere to receive the incoming message, and route it to your PC. If you go with Nexmo, here's a service that will connect to your account, and handle all that for you (including a google chrome plugin): [InDash: Incoming SMS Dashboard](http://indash.meltedcube.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to receive large numbers of SMS, then you are looking at having an SMS receiving server connected by an internet connection to the SMSC (Short Message Service Centre) in the operator's network.

Here is a commercial product that offers this service: http://www.ozeki.hu/index.php?owpn=507
Disclaimer: I have nothing to do with this company, I just post the link because they have a neat diagram that illustrates the concept.

It isn't that hard to write this server yourself - you need to use a protocol like SMPP (Short Message Peer to Peer protocol) to connect to the SMSC, and store the SMSs.

Comment: rather i am looking for a good short code provider who has PAN world access. i was mining the net but could get only county specific providers. The link you provided is gud, but i dont want to get into that hassle of setting up things myself, i dont hink my need will be daily its on demand basis. thanks a lot for the reply.